# LibGDX how to move something around a point

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to Java, Android and LibGDX, so forgive me if what I am asking for is simple.  What I would like, is for that grey thing (drawn badly, is meant to be a cannon) to swing around as the arrows show. Also, what could I use to get a more natural motion, e.g as if gravity is acting on the cannon, with it being slowest when it turns to its sides and fastest as it aims towards the ground. What could I use to make sure that the cannon keeps swinging and so that it doesn't lose momentum? This is where I may start to sound stupid... I have seen some tutorials online, but I don't fully understand how certain aspects of making games work. What would I have to create within my Java class? What is a Sprite and do I need to create one? What is a spritebatch? I understand the basics such as needing a game state manager, etc. Most of the stuff I pretty much copied from the tutorials, such as rendering a spritebatch( or something like that). If you could link me to some simple tutorials explaining the questions below, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a spritebatch?

We are drawing a lot of texture mapped to rectangular geometry in a frame but it would be inefficient to send each rectangle one at a time to the GPU to be drawn.So this is what spritebatch does.

```
private SpriteBatch batch;

public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}

public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
    batch.begin();
    // Drawing goes here!
    batch.end();
}
```

> What is sprite?

Sprite is a class describes texture and also some properties like color,angle ,offset etc.
Also everyframe when you draw texture CPU sends data to GPU.
However sprite sending texture data to GPU at creation and just changing its geometry or color when necessary.

```
private Sprite sprite;
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
sprite = new Sprite(texture, 20, 20, 50, 50);
sprite.setPosition(10, 10);
sprite.setRotation(45);
sprite.setCenter(25, 25);
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

As you can see its also answer of your first question. You can easly rotate sprite around its center.

> What could I use to make sure that the cannon keeps swinging and so that it doesn't lose momentum?

You can use box2d or you can design your own algorithm to swing.

> What would I have to create within my Java class?

You need to learn Object Oriented Programming for the answer.

and here is good libgdx tutorial 
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I have created a cannon sprite with a position. What could I do to get it's position in another class(my playstate class). I have a batch.draw(cannon.getTexture, ?, ?) in my playstate class, but I dont know what to put for the x and y positions. I have a getTexture method in my cannon class. If I was to create a getPosition method in my cannon class, what would It return with? How do I get the position from a sprite after I have used .setPosition?

Comment: you should create public variables in canon class. and call it canon.x canon.y